# Image returned from package gapfill different than raster plot

Tags: r

The Image function from package gapfill (gapfill::Image) returns a plot that looks different than the raster layer associated with it. Is it because the input of Image is an array and this makes the output not comparable with the plot of the raster?

I have a stack of raster layers in which I converted to an array following instructions in previous thread here (code below).

R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)

> gapfill package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gapfill/index.html

list_of_rasters is a list of rasters. Each raster has dimensions c(71,114). There is a raster for every day for 14 years. After that I transform the stacked to an array.

```
library(raster)
library(gapfill)

stacked <- stack(list_of_rasters)

tmp <- array(stacked, dim=c(71,114,365,14))
input_array <- aperm(tmp, c(2,1,3,4))

plot(stacked[[1]]) #plot of the raster for first day of the first year 1
Image(input_array[,,1,1]) #plot of the array for first day of the first year 2
```

Comment: Maybe I can help you if you provide a reproducible example. Maybe use `logo <- raster(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))` as image.